# Java Applet has strange quirks on clients running JRE 1.7

Tags: java, applet, java-7

I have an applet being served by Weblogic 10 running on Java 1.5. I have tried building the applet in question using Java 1.6 and Java 1.7, but both have the same quirk.

The thing is, when a client runs the applet using JRE 1.7, somehow functions are called from entirely different panels. This makes absolutely no sense, I know, but it is the case. Here is what happens:

The user loads the application and picks a data object to work with. There are two panels for this data object, a quick view and a detailed view. On the detailed view, the user can change the objects Asset Value, but not on the quick view. If they try changing the asset value, an alert will come up "Are you sure?". So, when on the quick view, they will randomly get these alerts making sure that they do in fact want to change the objects asset value, even though they aren't even on the screen where this is possible. Worse, other values on the detailed view are randomly changed to zeros or nulls, and since they don't require confirmation it immediately hits the Database.

Please note, we have lots of different java applications in our company, and only one has this problem. We ask our users not to install java 1.7, but every so often someone does and this application breaks. We then have to go and remove 1.7, then install 1.6 and everything is fine.

I have tried debugging this, but can't find anything anywhere. Also, I am not the author of the application and am simply tasked with finding the solution. Any help would be immensely appreciated, even some ideas as to where to look or how to debug this properly.

Answer (score 1):

> Mind, I am not doing much on applets lately.

An applet has methods with the following scopes:

```
{ init { start; stop } destroy }
```

The start/stop scope concerns an HTML page presented.

My guess is, that in `init` too much happens, or that `static` fields are used.

With `init` you could extend the old applet, using an empty `init`, and in `start` calling `super.init()`.
Likewise for `stop` / `destroy`.

Static fields can be seen by `javap` for instance. Then you indeed need to rewrite, but static fields are a definite no-go for applets.

The applet can be tested with `appletviewer` from the JDK's bin directory.

Comment: I looked over the application, and the only thing static are their constants. The start, stop and destroy are all blank, and the init 'seems' normal. I will start commenting out functionality there, maybe that will narrow down the problem.

Comment: Then it is a wild goose chase: ensure that actionPerformed calls first invokeLater. For JFrame a content pane (`getContentPane()`) was added from old to new Java, where `JFrame.add` actually adds to the content pane. `getParent` then goes wrong.